# Word Cloud getting blurry

Tags: javascript, canvas, word-cloud

I'm trying to draw the word cloud using wordcloud2.js:

```
var options = 
        {
         list : wordsSizeList,
         fontFamily: 'Finger Paint, cursive, sans-serif'
        }
WordCloud(target, options);
```

But my words are getting blurred (which might be because of low resolution image).

[image]

Wordcloud2.js uses canvas for drawing these words. So there should be some way to increase the pixel density of this canvas ?

Comment: Could you please provide your output (screenshot or something)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the size of the canvas like:

```
<canvas height="400" width="400" />
```

That should provide you a properly sized canvas (with higher resolution)